# UTF16 BIG ENDIAN to UTF8 conversion for failed for 0xdcf0

Tags: unicode

I am trying to convert a UTF16 to UTF8. For string 0xdcf0, the conversion failed with invalid multi byte sequence.  I don't understand why the conversion fails. In the library I am using to do utf-16 to utf-8 conversion, there is a  check

```
if (first_byte & 0xfc == 0xdc)  {
   return -1;
}
```

Can you please help me understand why this check is present.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 2.7: Strange Unicode behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53140775/python-2-7-strange-unicode-behavior)

Comment: [Is it possible to construct a unicode string that the utf-8 codec cannot encode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41231414/995714), [How to support surrogate characters in utf8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42556605/995714), [What are surrogate characters in UTF-8?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51001150/995714)

Answer (score 2):

Unicode characters in the `DC00–DFFF` range are "low" surrogates, i.e. are used in UTF-16 as the **second part** of a surrogate pair, the first part being a "high" surrogate character in the range `D800–DBFF`.

See e.g. Wikipedia article [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) for more information.

The reason you cannot convert to UTF-8, is that **you only have half a Unicode code point**.

Answer (score 1):

In UTF-16, the two byte sequence

```
DCFO
```

cannot begin the encoding of any character at all.

The way UTF-16 works is that some characters are encoded in 2 bytes and some characters are encoded in 4 bytes. The characters that are encoded with two bytes use 16-bit sequences in the ranges:

```
0000 .. D7FF
E000 .. FFFF
```

All other characters require four bytes to be encoded in UTF-16. For these characters the first pair of bytes must be in the range

```
D800 .. DBFF
```

and the second pair of bytes must be in the range

```
DC00 .. DFFF
```

This is how the encoding scheme is defined. See the [Wikipedia page for UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16).

Notice that the FIRST sixteen bits of an encoding of a character can NEVER be in DC00 through DFFF. It is simply not allowed in UTF-16. This is (if you follow the bitwise arithmetic in the code you found), exactly what is being checked for.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @JonathanLeffler! Wondering also if one could use the term "hextet"...it doesn't seem widely used outside of talking about IPv6 but does apply here too.